# Rails ActionController::ParameterMissing in QuestionsController#update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to create a boolean toggle button to change a value in my model Question. I am just learning rails so bear with me.

In my view I created a button:

```
<%= link_to("Answered", question_path(question, :status => true), :method => :put) %>
```

when I look at the URL for the button it is :

```
hackerQ.com/questions/8?status=true
```

This is the Error I am given.

```
Rails ActionController::ParameterMissing in QuestionsController#update

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def question_params
      params.require(:question).permit(:topic, :question, :status, :user_id, :teacher_id)
    end
end
```

My Question is should have have created a new action in my questions controller or added something to my params.require?

Comment: Request

Parameters:

{"_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"10YI0mmzH/R+otKFmEBJLPiQ0NhDIW+9dnFunMl8SCQ=",
 "status"=>"true",
 "id"=>"8"}

Comment: Post your update action in the QuestionsController.

Comment: https://github.com/TylerSangster/HackerQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller is looking for the :question parameter, but it cannot find it anywhere. You are not referencing :question anywhere, i think you have an error in the question_path() call. Try:

```
<%= link_to("Answered", question_path(:question, :status => true), :method => :put) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of the code:

```
params.require(:question)
```

your params hash has to have a "question" key, like this:

```
{"question" => {"status"=>"true"}` ...}
```

I don't know the proper way to get that. Maybe in link_to do:

```
link_to("Answered", question_path(question, "question[status]" => true), :method => :put)
```

Also, link_to creates an `<a>` tag.  Why are you calling that a button?  In html, a button and  a link are different things.

Answer (score 0):

No, you should have in your app something like this:

```
<%= form_for(question, method: :put) do |f| %>
  <% f.hidden_field :status, value: true %>
  <% f.submit "Answered" %>
<% end %>
```

I don't know if this is the right syntax, but you can't send those parameters over the URL.

Comment: Gives the Same error as my button. However it does not send the parameters over the net.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to debug is to print all the params you are passing to your controller from the view. You can do that by adding the following piece in your `html.erb` file(view):

```
<%= params.inspect %>
```

Or to print the value of the param your controller is expecting, use:

```
<%= params[:question] %>
```

where `question` is the name of the param you are expecting.

That will give you a clear picture of what you are passing or failing to pass.